# JS Cookie Shortlist - Add / Remove IDs on click

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, js-cookie

I'm building a holiday apartment website and would like to have a shortlist / favourites functionality. Cookies are fine for this purpose as there are no user logins.

Clicking 'Add to shortlist' on an apartment page would add the property's ID (200 for example) to an array saved in a cookie. Clicking it again would remove the ID. I can then use this array in my WordPress loop to display relevant properties on a shortlist page.

So if a user shortlists 4 apartments for example, the cookie would be a list of apartment IDs: 200,17,34,99

I'm using js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) in other places on the site, but this shortlist feature is too advanced for me.

Thanks for the help.

Cheers,
Klaye